# Filtering history in GitKraken by file names

Tags: gitkraken

I use GitKraken and would like to search/filter the repo history to locate commits involving certain files or (sub)paths.

I do can use CTRL+P and type the name in fuzzy finder and then get the file history but that brings me with only one branch-related history. And doesn't work for folders. So this is not enough.

My company is an 'enterprise monster' scale so I'd like to see a file or folder being affected on multiple branches at the same time, like it e.g. is available in TortoiseGit.

If the answer is 'not possible' - can someone point me to how they get feature requests (my feedback seemed not being prioritized high enough for such a simple and intuitive feature :) )?

Comment: Hello, did you ever find a solution to this? Especially filtering on a folder? We have a monorepo and I can't believe that nobody thought of this feature.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets Yes. I ditched Kraken in favor for the default Git-for-Windows's "View history" GUI. It is far from perfect but at least does what is necessary.

Comment: I found out that vscode with GitLens has a very nice filtering feature that works on folders too. Also, IntelliJ seems to have a similar feature. So I don't need a separate Git client, I can do everything from the IDE.